# Unable to pre assign values to ion-select-multiple

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I am using `ion-select-multiple`, I wish to pre assign values in it, which I am unable to do.

Have a look:

[image]

This is how I am trying to assign the authID in `this.followers`

```
this.followers = 'Ddy1QVOAO6SIvB8LfAE8Z0Adj4H3,12wsee3';
```

Here is my HTML code:

`home.html`

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Followers</ion-label>
    <ion-select multiple="true" okText="Okay" cancelText="Dismiss" [(ngModel)]="followers">
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let list of students;let i=index;" value="{{list.authId}}" checked="true">
        {{list.Name}}
      </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
  {{followers}}
</ion-list>
```

But 2 values are **not getting pre selected** when I open the page. How can I solve this?

### Edit 1

As guided by Tomas I tested with hard code values, code is below but no solution.

```
  <ion-select multiple="true" okText="Okay" cancelText="Dismiss" [(ngModel)]="followers" [value]="['brown', 'black']">
    <ion-select-option value="brown">Brown</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="blonde">Blonde</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="black">Black</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
```

Comment: A quick reminder: please use a capital letter when referring to yourself ("I"). There are no exceptions to this rule. Please have mercy on the volunteer editors here - we can fix your errors, but we'd rather not fix errors that are deliberate.

Comment: Please also refrain from adding "please help me" to your questions. This isn't all that polite - it is a coercive begging that implies you are in great distress, and that the reader is to feel socially obligated to render the help you demand. That is not appropriate for a volunteer forum. Moreover, if you keep on presenting yourself as needy, you will not become an incrementally better software engineer.

Comment: noted, i will take take care of this in future

Comment: Would you like to clarify _when_ in the future? Just trimmed a few more begging messages from you now.

Comment: The latest update for this question is "not working", which generally means the question as stated is lacking a [mcve]. If this question closes, it can be reopened once suitable clarifications are made.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax to pre-select multiple values:

```js
<ion-select multiple="true" [value]="['bird', 'dog']">
```

Documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#multiple-selection

So you want to assign your values to be preselected in the value property:

```js
<ion-select multiple="true" okText="Okay" cancelText="Dismiss" [(ngModel)]="followers" [value]="[followers]">
  <ion-select-option *ngFor="let list of students;let i=index;" value="{{list.authId}}">
    {{list.Name}}
  </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

Note that I haven't tested this code. If this fails, you might want to correct the input for the value property to a string array.

Comment: i tested this with hard code values even that didnt work